# Slight Confusion Regarding Expectation of Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I apologize if this question may sound a bit weird, but I'm self-studying probability theory and I'm a bit lost regarding the definition of expectation for random variables.

From what I understand, if X is a discrete random variable with range $R_x =$ $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$, then the expected value of $X$ is:

$$EX = \sum_{x_k \in R_x} x_kP(X=x_k)$$

Let's take a simple example. I toss a fair coin five times and define $X$ as the number of heads observed. Since $X$ is a binomial random variable, the expected value in this case is just $np = (5)(0.5) = 2.5$ which, correct me if I'm wrong, means that if I toss a fair coin five times, I'll observe 2.5 heads on average.

My point of confusion stems from thinking about another example in terms of the traditional definition of mean that we're used to (i.e. just sum up the values and divide by their count). So, let's say I define a random variable $Y$ as the scores of five students on a certain exam. Assume the scores (out of 100) were $\{70, 80, 65, 90, 50\}$. Isn't the mean in this case just the sum of values divided by their count here? I'm a bit lost where $P(Y = y_k)$ in the formula for expectation comes in to play here.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question regarding the scores.  If these are all of the test results, then yes.  The mean is the arithmetic average.  But if you mean that these are the unique scores observed, then you must weight them by their frequency.

Comment: @lulu Apologies, I just fixed my post. Thanks for the heads up! Also, regarding my question, I'm just confused how we're calculating the expected value of Y using the definition posted above.

Comment: If those were all the test scores (so only $5$ people took the test), then a (uniformly) randomly drawn score is equally likely to  be any of them, so $p_k=\frac 15$ for each $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

applying the definition of mean you posted, simply find

$$E(Y)=\sum_{i=1}^5Y_i\cdot P(Y=y_i)=70\times\frac{1}{5}+80\times\frac{1}{5}+65\times\frac{1}{5}+90\times\frac{1}{5}+50\times\frac{1}{5}=$$

$$=\frac{70+80+65+90+50}{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

Continuing the answer by @tommik, the arithmetic average of the values observed was a weighted sum: multiply each of the values by a "weight" of $1/5$ and sum:

$$ \frac{1}{5} *70 + \frac{1}{5}*80 + \frac{1}{5}* 65 + \frac{1}{5}* 90 + \frac{1}{10} *50.$$

Note that the weight is the proportion of students receiving this grade.

Let's now observe the *same* set of grades but in a slightly different scenario:

- 10 students;
- 1 getting 70, 2 getting 80, 3 getting 65, 3 getting 90 and 1 getting 50.

What would you consider now as the average grade? I guess your answer will change a little because some values are repeated. A similar calculation will yield an answer of the form

$$ \frac{1}{10} *70 + \frac{2}{10}*80 + \frac{3}{10}* 65 + \frac{3}{10}* 90 + \frac{1}{10} *50.$$

Namely, same grade values, but different weights, each weight representing the proportion of students receiving that grade and all weights add up to $1$.

Now for expectation. The notion of expectation in probability is the generalization of a weighted average, the generalization (in the discrete case) being weights provided by the particular probability measure we are using (and there are many choices: theoretically any assignments of nonnegative weights adding up to $1$ is possible, so very important to specify the probability measure we're using in not clear from the context). The examples we saw were of two different choices of probability measures yielding two different sets of weights.

The expression

$$ \sum P(X= x_k) x_k$$

Should be viewed as the weighted average of the values $\{x_k\}$ with weight assigned to $x_k$ represented by $P(X=x_k)$ ("the probability that $X$ is equal to $x_k$").